# Inheritance In spock Framework. I want to reuse testing cases in multiple specs

Tags: grails, spock

In my project I have many domain objects that are very similar between each other. While designing the tests I realized that a lot of the test cases were identical. So I set myself to create a BaseSpec that would enable me to reuse logic and code.

- Is the approach I describe below correct.
- How would I execute all my unit tests except BaseSpec?

Suppose I have the following two grails domain classes:

```
class Product{
    String productName
    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
    }

}

class Category{
    String categoryName
    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
    }
}
```

First I would need a Spec to be used as a base. This base would have the common tests for both ProductSpec and Category Spec.

```
@Mock([Product, Category])  //? is this needed
class BaseSpec extends Specification {
    @Shared classForTest
    @Shared constructor
    @Shared nameParam

    def setup(){
        //This is what I would override in my child Tests
        //classForTest =  new Category().getClass()
        //constructor = classForTest.getConstructor()
        //nameParam = "categoryName"

    }


    def "Testing that the name field is unique"(){
        given: "A class instance"
            String testValue = "ABSCSD SDS SDS"
            def instance1 = constructor.newInstance()  //using the constructor to get an instance
            instance1."${nameParam}" = testValue
            instance1.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        and: "A duplicated Instance"
            def instance2 = constructor.newInstance()
            instance2."${nameParam}" = testValue
        expect: "The second instance should not save"
            shouldFail {instance2.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)}
    }

    //...Other common test cases


}
```

Then I would have a ProductSpec and a CategorySpec, and each should only override the setup of the BaseSpec.

```
@TestFor(Product)
class ProductSpec extends BaseSpec{
    @Override
    def setup(){
        classForTest =  new Product().getClass()  //Get the class that is testec
        constructor = classForTest.getConstructor() //Get the constructor of the tested class
        nameParam = "productName" //Establish the name of the parameter
    }

    //... Other Product Tests
}

@TestFor(Category)
class CategorySpec extends BaseSpec {
    @Override
    def setup(){
        classForTest =  new Category().getClass()
        constructor = classForTest.getConstructor()
        nameParam = "categoryName"
    }
    //... Other Category Tests
}
```

Comment: It is best if your parent class is not a spec itself but just a class with common functionality. Its methods should be called from the Spock blocks of the CategorySpec and ProductSpec

Comment: I think your approach is going in the right way. You can see an example from Spock repo at: https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/src/test/groovy/SpecInheritanceSpec.groovy. As @kazanaki mentioned, maybe make BaseSpec abstract class.
Regarding how to exclude BaseSpec take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/gajo4256/4f2c7079fedd840e2222. ATM as far as I know you can not do it out of the box with provided Spock annotations.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative to what I originally posted. **It does not use inheritance** but it will allow testing cases where the testing cases are very similar.

```
Consider the domain classes
class Product{
    String productName
    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
    }

}

class Category{
    String categoryName
    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true
    }
}
```

As a very simple example we want to test the validation of productName and categoryName. So we could have a test like:

```
@Mock([Product, Category])
class CatalogSimpleGenericSpec extends Specification {

    def "Validation of test field in a given domain"(){
        given: "A new instance of the domain"
            def testInstance = constructorOfInstance.newInstance()  //Creating the instance using the constructor
            testInstance."${fieldName}" = fieldValue 
            testInstance.validate()

        expect: "Testing if the instance should save depending on the value of shouldHaveErrors"
            assert testInstance.hasErrors() == shouldHaveErrors //Verifying if it should have errors

            //If there are errors the instance should fail to save, otherwise it will save perfectly
            shouldHaveErrors ?
                shouldFail {testInstance.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)}
                : testInstance.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        where:
            constructorOfInstance                               | shouldHaveErrors  | fieldName | fieldValue                | reasoning
            //-----------------  PRODUCT ----------------------
            new Product().getClass().getConstructor()           | false             | "productName" | "Folders"             | "Should pass since a product name is supplied"
            new Product().getClass().getConstructor()           | true              | "productName" | ""                    | "Should fail empty strings should not be accepted"
            new Product().getClass().getConstructor()           | true              | "productName" | null                  | "Should fail null values shoult not be accepted"

            //----------------- CATEGORY --------------------
            new Category().getClass().getConstructor()          | false             | "categoryName" | "Office Supplies"    | "Should pass since a category name is supplied"
            new Category().getClass().getConstructor()          | true              | "categoryName" | ""                   | "Should fail empty strings should not be accepted"
            new Category().getClass().getConstructor()          | true              | "categoryName" | null                 | "Should fail null values shoult not be accepted"
    }


}
```

Instead of using inheritance I am getting the constructor of an instance of the domain, and then using that constructor **(constructorOfInstance)** to build my instance **(testInstance)**. The field value is assigned using `testInstance."${fieldName}" = fieldValue`. And we test wheter or not the save should fail using the value of **shouldHaveErrors**.